# More efficient if else block statements

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring, boolean-logic

I'm trying to recreate a printer in java,I'm fairly new to programming so I'm using huge if else blocks inside a single function to dictate the logic of the program, I'm noticing this is creating a mass of code inside the same function, I was wondering if there was a more eloquent/efficient way of doing this, printer class below. Logic for the printer isn't too important, but just to show anyway, one is a double sided printer one isn't, and logic is in charge of checking toner levels and making sure pages printed are in line with printer being double sided or not.

```
package com.company;


public class Printer {
private String name;
private double tonerLevel = 100;
private int ammountOfPaper;
private int numberOfPagesPrinted;
private boolean isDoubleSided;

public Printer(String name, double tonerLevel, int ammountOfPaper, boolean isDoubleSided) {
    this.name = name;
    if(tonerLevel >= 0 && tonerLevel <= 100) {
        this.tonerLevel = tonerLevel;
    }
    this.ammountOfPaper = ammountOfPaper;
    this.isDoubleSided = isDoubleSided;
}

private boolean isOutOfToner(double numberToPrint) {
    if((tonerLevel - (numberToPrint / 2) < 0)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}


private boolean isOutOfPaper(double numberToPrint) {
    if(((ammountOfPaper - numberToPrint) < 0)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean twoSideNoPaperEven(double numberToPrint) {
    if((ammountOfPaper - ((int) numberToPrint / 2)) < 0 ) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean twoSideNoPaperOdd(double numberToPrint) {
    if(((ammountOfPaper - ((int) numberToPrint / 2)) - 1) < 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void printPages(double numberToPrint) {

    if(isDoubleSided == false) {
        if(tonerLevel == 0) {
            System.out.println("Out of toner");
        }
        if(ammountOfPaper == 0) {
            System.out.println("Out of Paper");
        }
        if(isOutOfToner(numberToPrint) && (tonerLevel != 0)) {
            double difference = tonerLevel * 2;
            numberToPrint = difference;
            ammountOfPaper -= numberToPrint;
            System.out.println("Will run out of toner after this print, able to print " + (int) numberToPrint +
                    " pages");
            tonerLevel = 0;
        }
        if(isOutOfPaper(numberToPrint) && (ammountOfPaper != 0)) {
            double different = ammountOfPaper - numberToPrint;
            numberToPrint = numberToPrint + different;
            System.out.println("Will run out of paper after this print, printing " + (int) numberToPrint + " pages");
            ammountOfPaper = 0;
        }
        else if(!isOutOfToner(numberToPrint) && (!isOutOfPaper(numberToPrint))) {
            ammountOfPaper -= numberToPrint;
            tonerLevel = tonerLevel - (numberToPrint / 2);
            showPages(numberToPrint);
        }

    }
    else if(isDoubleSided = true) {
            if (numberToPrint % 2 == 0) {
                if(tonerLevel == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Out of Toner");
                }
                if(ammountOfPaper == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Out of Paper");
                }
                if(twoSideNoPaperEven(numberToPrint) && (ammountOfPaper != 0)) {
                    ammountOfPaper -= numberToPrint / 2;
                    System.out.println("There is no Paper");
                }
                else if(!twoSideNoPaperEven(numberToPrint)) {
                    tonerLevel = tonerLevel - (numberToPrint / 2);
                    ammountOfPaper -= numberToPrint / 2;
                    showPages(numberToPrint);
                }
            } else {
                if(tonerLevel == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Out of Toner");
                }
                if(ammountOfPaper == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Out of Paper");
                }
                if(twoSideNoPaperOdd(numberToPrint) && (ammountOfPaper != 0)) {
                    System.out.println("There is no paper");
                    ammountOfPaper = (ammountOfPaper - ((int) numberToPrint / 2)) - 1;
                    ammountOfPaper = 0;
                }
                else if(!twoSideNoPaperOdd(numberToPrint)) {
                    tonerLevel = tonerLevel - (numberToPrint / 2);
                    ammountOfPaper = (ammountOfPaper - ((int) numberToPrint / 2)) - 1;
                    showPages(numberToPrint);
                }
            }
        }

    }

public void showPages(double numberToPrint) {
    System.out.println("Printing " + (int) numberToPrint + " Pages, paper remaining is: " + this.ammountOfPaper
            + " Toner level is: " + this.tonerLevel);
}

public void refillToner() {
    tonerLevel = 100;
}
public void refillPaper(int paper) {
    if(paper > 50) {
        System.out.println("Cannot put in more paper");
    }
    else {
        this.ammountOfPaper += paper;
    }
}

public int getAmmountOfPaper() {
    return ammountOfPaper;
}

public double getTonerLevel() {
    return tonerLevel;
}

public void setTonerLevel(double tonerLevel) {
    this.tonerLevel = tonerLevel;
}

public void setAmmountOfPaper(int ammountOfPaper) {
    this.ammountOfPaper = ammountOfPaper;
}
```

Changing the If Statements To as suggested by nicolas:

```
 public void printPages(double numberToPrint) {
 if(tonerLevel == 0) {
        System.out.println("Out of toner");
        return;
    }
    if(ammountOfPaper == 0) {
        System.out.println("Out of Paper");
        return;
    }

if(isDoubleSided == false) {
```

Comment: `if` statements evaluate to boolean values anyways, there's no point in doing `if (somecondition) return true else return false`, you could just do `return somecondition`. but that's not really more or less efficient, it just eliminates a few lines of redundant code.

Comment: Use early out, i.e. `if( tonerLevel == 0 ) { System.out. ...; return; }`  etc. Thus you don't have to check again and again. Also try to factor out different branches like single-sided or double-sided to different methods or classes (e.g. subclasses or strategy pattern).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted on a better suited Stack Exchange site. In future, please only post your question on a single Stack Exchange site. For more information, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138774/simulating-a-printer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your  `if-statements` are redundant. You can return directly the boolean value. It saves you 12 lines in your code. For example:

   ```
   private boolean twoSideNoPaperOdd(double numberToPrint) {
       return ((ammountOfPaper - ((int) numberToPrint / 2)) - 1) < 0;
   }
   ```
2. There are few conditions repeated often with the same result. Again, it shortens the class by 24 lines.

   ```
   if (tonerLevel == 0) {
       System.out.println("Out of toner");
       return; // leave the rest of method
   }

   if (ammountOfPaper == 0) {
       System.out.println("Out of Paper");
       return
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I've added a bit of an addendum to my question if you wouldn't mind looking at it, are you saying to put the if(tonerLevel) and if(ammountOfPaper) statements at the top of the function, I was wondering if I could get a bit of clarification on what adding the return will achieve as well, appreciate the feedback, thank you!

Comment: One advantage of NOT returning immediately on the first error is that the output error messages will contain all of the steps needed to solve the problem. If you return immediately after the first error message, the user corrects the problem and tries again only to get another error; she fixes that and tries again, only to run into another problem, By this time, I would be kicking the #%$@ machine, yelling "Why didn't you tell me that the last two times I tried?!!!"